# How to rotate skeleton segments in Three JS skinning example?

Tags: three.js, quaternions, rotational-matrices

I would like to use [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_additive_blending.html) Three JS example in my project. But I have my own dataset of movements I would like to implement, consisting of quaternion rotations of each segment (hands, arms, trunk...). However, I am new to using Three JS and JavaScript in general. Can I access the skeleton parts in

```
skeleton = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( model );
```

and apply the rotations? and how?

E.g. I would like to apply the following rotation to the elbow joint:

```
quat = [0.5412077307701111,-0.5664581656455994,-0.34294596314430237,-0.5182857513427734]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the following code to get the specific joint and then apply the quaternion as so:

```
rightArm = model.getObjectByName( 'mixamorigRightArm' );


rightArm.quaternion.set(w,x,y,z);
```